# slideUp/Down not working with a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Hello I'm trying to fix a bug in a bigger program and the bug is related to slideUp/Down not working within a dialog when the dialog is initially hidden. I've made a [jsbin test case](http://jsbin.com/inohul). The intended behavior is that "panel 1" text should slide up and be hidden. The actual behavior is that nothing really appears to happen.

How do I fix this problem or work around it?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by carrying the slideUp function to the open event inside the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#diag').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    open: function(){
      $('#pnl1').slideUp('slow');
    }
  });
  $('#diag').show();  
  $('#diag').dialog('open');
});
```

I also added $('#diag').show(); to be on the safe side.

For a performance boost you might want to store the elements into their own vars instead of having JQuery traverse the DOM to look for them each time. For instance:

```
var diag= $('#diag');
diag.dialog('open');
```

Comment: is it possible to do "late binding" for the open-dialog event? For instance to have no `open` event initially and attach it later on?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly by setting the open event later?
Also I realize that instead of having to set the open event function you can simply have $('#pnl1').slideUp('slow'); show up on top of $('#diag').dialog({ ... }) and it works just fine.

Comment: It's just to make it so I don't have to do a whole lot of restructuring

Comment: Sure, in order to bind the open event later type in this code: `$( '#diag' ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
  $('#pnl1').slideUp('slow');
});`. This will only take effect obviously if you reopen the dialog box afterwards.